# WAP in Java to print the sequence 1 32 456 10987

Tags: java, sequence

I am unable to crack the algorithm for this one.

Question: WAP in JAVA to print the sequence

1

3*2

4*5*6

10*9*8*7

11*12*13*14*15

Please Help. !!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Show your attempts please.

Comment: Be clear with the question.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
final int n = 15;

int i = 1;
int cnt = 1;
boolean ltr = true;
while (i < n)
{
    String s = "";
    if (ltr)
        for (int j=0; j<cnt; j++)
            s = s + ( s.length() > 0 ? "*" : "") + i++;
    else
        for (int j=0; j<cnt; j++)
            s = i++ + ( s.length() > 0 ? "*" : "") + s;
    cnt++;
    ltr=!ltr;
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Well done. People shouldn't even try themselves, they can always count on you to provide the full working code.

Comment: @IIya Bursov That was harsh. I am new to programming altogether and came across this question while practicing my concepts, although, i wasn't able to get through due to the lack of experience/practice. So you can say i was caught in a loop. I did try hard but could never reach close and that was when i decided to ask some wise men!! Thank you for your comments anyway, they are encouraging and thought provoking! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PatternOddEven {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        int k=1,l=1,m=1,x=1;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            System.out.println();
            if(i%2!=0)
            {
                for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
                {

                    System.out.print(l++);
                    int a=1;
                    if(a<=j && j!=i)
                    {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }
                }

                k=l+m*2;
                m++;
                l--;
            }
            else
            {
                l=k+1;
                x=k;
                for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
                {

                    System.out.print(--x);
                    int a=1;
                    if(a<=j && j!=i)
                    {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    }
                }   
                l--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here it is bro use it for any number you will got answer

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   int n,k=0;
   n=sc.nextInt();
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
     if(i%2==0)
     {
         for(int y=0;y<i;y++)
         {
             System.out.print(++k+"*");
         }
         System.out.print(++k);
     }
     else
     {
         int t=k+i+1;
         for(int x=0;x<i;x++)
         {
             System.out.print((t--)+"*");
         }
         System.out.print(t--);
         k=k+i+1;
     }
       System.out.println();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## python 3 solution:

```
1
3*2
4*5*6
10*9*8*7
11*12*13*14*15
.
.
to the nth row...


n = int(input())
k = 1
res = ''
for i in range(n):
if i % 2 == 0:
    for j in range(i+1):
        res = res + str(k) +"*"
        k += 1
    print(res[:-1])
    res = ''
else:
    k += i
    for j in range(i+1):
        res = res + str(k) +"*"
        k -= 1
    print(res[:-1])
    res = ''
    k += i
```

Comment: Give some explanation of your solution.

Comment: Algorithm:  1> Take an empty string 'res'   
2> where the row value  % 2 == 0 print from beginning and increment k by 1after every iterartion 
3> where row value % 2 ! == 0 increment k by row value first than print by from last value of k and decrement k by 1 after each iteration 
4> concatenate 'res' by str(k) and "*" , convert int to string just only for concatenation
5> print(res[:-1]) to remove trailing "*" form string.

Answer (score -1):

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sample {

```
/**To print
 * 1
 * 3*2
 * 4*5*6
 * 10*9*8*7
 * 11*12*13*14*15
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    int b=0,a;
    System.out.println("Enter the limit:");
    int n=s.nextInt();
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++) {
                b=b+1;
            }
            a=b;
            for (int j=1;j<=i;j++) {
                System.out.print(a--);
                if (j != i) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        } else {
            for (int k=1;k<=i;k++) {
                b=b+1;
                System.out.print(b);
                if (k != i) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

}
```